# Base class Generic and inheritance class .NET

Tags: c#, generics

I don't know if this is the right title, so apologies for that if it isn't!

I've got a base class which will be used to store an exception if any occur:

```
public class BaseException
{
    public bool HasException { get; set; }
    public string ExceptionMessage { get; set; }
}
```

I've got other classes that will inherit from my base class:

```
public class BoolValue : BaseException
{
    public bool Value { get; set; }
}

public class LongValue : BaseException
{
    public bool Value { get; set; }
}
```

So when I call it, it will be

```
function LongValue MyFirstFunction()
{
    LongValue data = new LongValue();

    try
    {
        data = ....    
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        data = BuildException<LongValue>(ex, data);
        return data;
    }
    finally
    {
        data = null;
    }
}

function BoolValue MySecondFunction()
{
    BoolValue data = new BoolValue();
    try
    {
        data = ....
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        data = BuildException<BoolValue>(ex, data);
        return data;
    }
    finally
    {
        data = null;
    }
}
```

I want to create Generic function where I'll be able set the exception details if an error occurs, but return the original class type i.e. LongValue or LongBool

```
protected T BuildException<T>(Exception exception, T obj)
{

}
```

But I'm sure how to set the HasException and ExceptionMessage, as even casting it doesn't work as the compiler is telling me I can't convert a T to BaseException

```
((BaseException)data).HasException = true;
```

I would like my final function to be something like this:

```
protected T BuildException<T>(Exception exception, T data)
{
  ((BaseException)data).HasException = true;
  ((BaseException)data).ExceptionMessage = exception.Message;
  return data;
}
```

Is there a way I can achieve this or should I just create an Interface for my BaseException?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't want to put it in my answer because it's not about your question, but are you sure your design is OK? Class with name ending with `Exception` which does not inherit from `Exception` class may not be a good idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set [generic constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) on your method:

```
protected T BuildException<T>(Exception exception, T data) where T : BaseException
{
    data.HasException = true;
    data.ExceptionMessage = exception.Message;
    return data;
}
```